# How Would I grab the value of my input boxes to print my own custom message?

Tags: json, reactjs, input, state

I have a json that consists of a parent name and kids that the parent has.

I have a code that grabs the name of the parent and the kids of the json . Based on the amount of kids, input boxes are created so you can enter the name of each kid. But I am stuck. When I click the button how would I print a message that starts with the parent name and combines the values from each input box from the values of the json and the boxes that allow me to name the child

for instance when I click 'jim' from the dropdown, 2 input boxes shows up that says 'child1' and 'child2' and two boxes shows up next to them because he has two children. if i name child1 "james" and child2 "mary" and push the button how can I print a message in the final input box that says

"Jim -- child1=james -- child2=mary"

```
import React from 'react';

class AppEX extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            kids: null,
            parentname: null,
            parent: [
                { name: 'will', kids: ['child1', 'child2'] },
                { name: 'kia', kids: ['child1'] },
                { name: 'jim', kids: ['child1', 'child2'] }
            ]
        };
    }

    handleParentChoice = e => {
        e.persist();
        this.setState({
            parentname: e.target.value
        });
    };

    render() {
        const namelist = [];
        this.state.parent.forEach(e => {
            namelist.push({ value: e.name, label: e.name });
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <select name="select" onChange={this.handleParentChoice}>
                    {namelist.map(n => (
                        <option key={n.value} value={n.value}>
                            {n.label}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <br />
                {this.state.parentname &&
                    this.state.parent
                        .find(p => p.name === this.state.parentname)
                        .kids.map(k => (
                            <div>
                                <input
                                    key={k}
                                    type="text"
                                    value={k}
                                    disabled={true}
                                />
                                <input key={k} type="text" />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                <br />
                <button type="button" value="render" onClick={this.print} />
                <input type="text" disabled={true} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppEX;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-johnson-zst0q?file=/src/App.js), which does what you need.

Note that I had to add/modify some `key` attributes at places, because there were some console errors.

Also you need to synchronize input values to state at some point. **In this example I do it on each keystroke, but you must be aware of the performance implications of this.** You may choose different timing for the sync (on blur, with some debounce, etc.), it's up to you.

I modified inputs' name attributes so that each one has unique one, and can be recognized in the function which syncs to state (`onChildNameChange`).

And btw there are some nice libraries which can spare you the boilerplate of syncing, like [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) (functional components, only) and [formik](https://formik.org/).

As for printing the output string, I used `Array.reduce` to build it.

Comment: but where this --'child' what would I change if i wanted that to be the actual value of chiild instead of string. for instance what if i added 'infant' instead of child and now it would say --infant and not because i set it as a string of 'infant' ?

Comment: Can you clarify on what needs to be editable and what readonly? Currently you can modify the value through the normal input, in this example I put child1, child2, ... as just a readonly label. I thought this was some sort of a counter.

Comment: Here's another sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-cdn-538me?file=/src/App.js  I introduced another array ```prefixes``` which I assume was supposed to be readonly. Now ```prefixes``` are taken from there, instead of hardcoding them to child1, child2, etc. I assume to keep those prefixes as readonly values and the names editable. Code assumes that prefixes are equal to children for a given parent.

Comment: than you! I think i am running into some sync issues though. When i type into the input boxes nothing shows up in them

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Here's what I see when I type: https://i.imgur.com/mYPwPUe.gif

Comment: well two things: the value of my dropdown doesn't change when I select and option (but it does render the child boxes) . and when i type inside of the name input boxes it doesn;t change but the disabled child boxes changes based on what I type but only by only allows one character.

Comment: I couldn't understand. Can you explain what is still wrong with the screencast I provided - there the dropdown's value changes and so do the input's value upon typing.